# h:selectOneMenu default value issue when put it in h:dataTable

Tags: datatable, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I have a problem with `h:selectOneMenu`.
If I put it in `h:dataTable` I'm unable to set the default value.
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
              xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
              xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:dataTable value="#{utenteBean.listaUtenti}"
                 var="utente"  >
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="1"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{sW.headerUsername}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText escape="false"
                          value="#{utente.username}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{sW.headerEnabled}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:form>
                <h:commandLink action="#{utenteBean.updateAbilitato}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{utente.enabled}">
                        <f:converter converterId="abilitatoConverter"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{utenteBean.utente}"
                                                 value="#{utente}"/>
                </h:commandLink>
            </h:form>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{sW.headerRuolo}" />
            </f:facet>
                <h:form>
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="ROLE_ADMIN"
                                     valueChangeListener="#{utenteBean.updateRuolo}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Utente" itemValue="ROLE_USER"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Admin" itemValue="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</ui:component>
```

If I move the `h:form` with `selectOneMenu` out of `h:dataTable` all works.
I'm using jsf2.0 on glassfish3

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

(Solved by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I have solved it by myself, i think there is a bug in `<h:selectOneMenu value="ROLE_ADMIN"` i changed the value="" from static to dynamic with a reference to an istance in managed bean and all work perfectly.